# Sort email list by domain

Tags: c#, list, email

i wanna actuelly sort a list with email addresses by their domain.
Lets say for an example:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(a@hotmail.com);
list.Add(b@aon.at);
list.Add(c@gmail.com);
```

so the result should be:

```
b@aon.at
c@gmail.com
a@hotmail.com
```

is that possible without splitting the email addresses ?

Comment: You should use your mail address as a string like `"a@hotmail.com"` by the way..

Comment: i know that i should do it but i just typed it fastly in here ... sorry ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex to get domain of the emails:

```
var listSorted = list.OrderBy(email => Regex.Match(email, "@.*").Value)
                     .ToList();
```

because:

```
var temp = Regex.Match("a@hotmail.com", "@.*").Value;
```

tells: take everything after `@` sign (including `@` sign) so `temp` will be `@hotmail.com` in this case.

Comment: actuelly this was what i needed in programm :) all answers worked but i think thats the best way to do it aslong is i have string for my emails... but theres a problem hes sorting everything but at the end (after x,y,z) there he starts again and not sorted an thats kinda strange i cant copy the addresses where it happens in here because of privacy .. ive a list of 1.5k emails do you know why that happens ?

Comment: yline.com
    ymail.com
    ymail.com
   .zakpharma.at
   .zaltech.com
    zebe.at
    zumaltenweinstock.at
    strein.cc
    hotmail.fr
    interspot.at

like this before that happens its everything perfectly sorted .. as i wish but the last ,,lets say 100" addresses are not sorted anymore and i don t get why

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(x=>new MailAddress(x).Host).ToList();
```

it will sort your email addresses by mail host

Comment: Wow ! the power of LINQ

Comment: thanks for this fast help. was exactly what i needed thanks a lot

Comment: Well, in this case more the power of `MailAddress`.

Comment: @RamonHämmerle: Make sure to accept the working answer for you. There is the check mark next to each answer. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @RamonHämmerle no problem :) good to hear that it was helpful :)

Comment: can i also do it with strings instead of MailAddress ? is that possible without splitting ?

Comment: @RamonHämmerle it should contain email adress

Comment: hmm okay im gonna change my programm from string to mailaddress :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use linq for this. However it is absolutely necessary that you split the email address:

```
list.OrderBy(email => email.Split('@')[1]).ToList();
```

Comment: wudzik answered it allready :) i knew how it works with splitting thats why i asked without splitting :) and it works but thanks for ur help anyways !